# How to create a cylinder which fits snugly to an existing ring

Tags: modeling

I want to add a cylinder which will snugly fit an already round object that I have imported. I can select all the edges in the ring like this:

[image]

Now I want to add a cylinder which will have the exact same circumference/diameter as the selected ring so that I can merge them together to continue this round object.

How can I do this?

Comment: Extrude the selected ring downwards?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try *Extrude Region* tool in the tool bar.

Select the edge and drag the `+` handle:

[image]

You can also use <kbd>E</kbd> shortcut.